# InfluxDB error "Odd number of parameters to new()" when run on a loop

Tags: perl, influxdb

I would like to know how to avoid the "Odd number of parameters to new()" error on the following code(simplified). The code works only for the first iteration.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use InfluxDB;

for (;;) {
    load1();
    sleep 5;
}

sub load1 {
    my $ix = InfluxDB->new(host => '192.168.0.93', port => 8086, username => 'root', password => 'root', database => 'test');
    ## do some stuffs ...
}
```

I have tried to research on this but i cant find the way to use shift or bless functions to solve this.

I have edited the InfluxDB module to print the passed parameters.This is what i have discovered;

For the first iteration:

```
    Mouse::Meta::Class::__ANON__::2=HASH(0x2359398)
    host
    192.168.0.93
    port
    8086
    username
    root
    password
    root
    database
    test_database
```

For the second iteration:

```
    Mouse::Meta::Class::__ANON__::6=HASH(0x2359398)
    192.168.0.93
    port
    8086
    username
    root
    password
    root
    database
    test_database
```

So as we can see, for the second iteration there is no "host". I once saw this behaviour when calling the function new with the :: (ex. InfluxDB::new()) instead of ->(InfluxDB->new).

Comment: To solve the immediate problem, you could move the `$ix` declaration outside of the function so that it is only called once.

Comment: I tried that yesterday and i got the same result..

Comment: This is a bug indeed and it is fixed now (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug for me. You can try to fix it or wait for the [author's response](https://github.com/hirose31/p5-InfluxDB/issues/5).

*UPDATE:* This is a bug indeed and it is [fixed](https://github.com/hirose31/p5-InfluxDB/issues/5#issuecomment-100128889) now. Update your `InfluxDB` module.

Comment: Answering the problem and logging a bug report? Now that's worth a +1 :)

Comment: @Johns, you can also mark this answer as a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on InfluxDB directly, as that looks like a github project that's in alpha. If there's bugs there, then it's one for the maintainer(s) to address. That said:

The 'odd number of parameters' is *usually* when you're trying to cast an array to a hash.

E.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
my @array = qw ( a 1 b 2 c 3 4 ):
my %hash = @array;
```

"Odd number of elements in hash assignment"

The reason this applies to constructors - such as `new()` is because when you call:

```
use SomeModule;
my $thing = SomeModule -> new();
```

Is that form of call implicitly passes the class. E.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package SomeModule;

sub new {
  print "New got args: @_\n";
}

package main; 
my $thing = SomeModule -> new();
```

So when you pass in a hash to use in the constructor, you first need to 'pop off' that class name. It's good form to specify it in `bless`.

Something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

package SomeModule;

sub new {
  print "New got args: @_\n";
  my ( $class, %options ) = @_; 
  my $self = \%options;
  bless ( $self, $class );
  return $self;
}

package main; 
my $thing = SomeModule -> new(host => '192.168.0.93', port => 8086, username => 'root', password => 'root', database => 'test');
print Dumper $thing;
```

This is much the same as how when you invoke a method:

```
$thing -> some_method($other_argument);
```

The first argument is a reference to the object, and it's fundamentally similar to:

```
SomeModule::some_method($thing, $other_argument);
```

Comment: That is not the case. It looks like a `InfluxDB` bug, run the example.

Comment: I saw "InfluxDB v0.9.0 is now in the alpha phase" and decided that might well be the case - so tried to offer something more useful :)